# Android studio keeps showing "Loading..." on device selector

Tags: macos, android-studio, flutter, adb

I got stuck in this problem for several days, my android studio suddenly keep showing 'Loading...' on its device selector when there are active android emulator or connected to android device. [image: android device selector]

i use mac os catalina 10.15.5 and here is some clue that might help :

```
siekoo-mac:~ siekoo$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-ID)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS
      development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin
        code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install:
        sudo gem install cocoapods
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

siekoo-mac:~ siekoo$ adb devices
List of devices attached
16fb14c20205    device
```

Ive tried several solutions, like run invalidate & cache restart on android studio, reinstalling adb platform tools, reinstalling android SDKs or even downgrade/upgrade the android studio, all doesnt end with good result. For now, i run my project on android device via terminal

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due to different compile and target SDK versions inside app level gradle and library gradle. It was resolved by changing sdk versions from 26 to 29 in both.

Answer (score 0):

Open another android project in new window (not a flutter project). Now you have two windows of android studio.
then device will detect on Android project. You will be able to connect your device for native android project. Then try again to detect device on flutter project.
Your device will show here.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

1. Open in Android Studio - Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Flutter
2. Set path SDK .../SDK/flutter